# How to chain shell command with vim Ex command?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to do the following:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.py :!isort % | :edit
```

The `isort` command in this case is writing to the buffer and so I'd like to reload the buffer to see the changes to the file I'm currently viewing.

But i find that because I've triggered a shell command `!` the pipe is interpreted as part of the shell command and not as part of a chained vim Ex command.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried grouping the shell command so it was separate from the pipe/Ex command (In my head I imagined some magic making this work sort of like a subprocess):

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.py :(!isort %) | :edit
```

But that was invalid.

Thanks.

Comment: This might be useful too: https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/wiki/isort-Plugins

Answer (score 6):

The help for `:!` says:

> ```
> A '|' in {cmd} is passed to the shell, you cannot use
> it to append a Vim command.  See |:bar|.
> ```

The usual workaround is to use `:execute`, which can be followed by `|`:

```
:execute '!isort %' | edit
```

One last note, though: it is possible to use the `:!` form as a filter (see `:help :range!`), meaning I would use the following code instead:

```
:%!isort
```

This runs `isort` with stdin as the contents of the buffer. It replaces the buffer with the output of the command.

Comment: [`isort`](https://pypi.org/project/isort/) only sorts Python `import` statements (according to specific rules) and not sort the whole contents of the file... So built-in sort is not really a replacement here.